# Derivation of out-vacuum in terms of in-vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Say that spacetime undergoes an expansion, and the quantum field is in the state $\phi_{in}$ at $t \rightarrow -\infty$ and $\phi_{out}$ at $t \rightarrow \infty$. The annihilation operators can be related via a Bogoliubov transform, and some reordering gives

$a(k)^{out}|0_{in}\rangle$ = $-\frac{\beta_k}{\alpha_k}a^{\dagger}(k)^{out}|0_{in}\rangle$ where $\alpha$ $\beta$ are the Bogoliubov coefficients. The aim is to write out the in vacuum in terms of the out vacuum. My reference uses a rather crude derivation, and says $a^{out}(k) = \frac{\partial}{\partial{a^{\dagger}(k)}}$. The resulting differential equation is

$$\frac{\partial{|0_{in}\rangle}}{\partial{a^{\dagger}(k)}} = -\frac{\beta_k}{\alpha_k}a^{\dagger}(k)^{out}|0_{in}\rangle.$$

Then by “integrating” both sides one gets

$\log\left(\frac{|0_{in}\rangle}{|0_{out}\rangle}\right)$ on the left hand side (though I’m pretty sure the author means to write a natural log)

I don’t see how $|0_{in}\rangle$ pops up. How was it introduced by the simple act of integrating?

Comment: What reference?

Comment: 107 https://www.sissa.it/app/phdsection/OnlineResources/104/Adv.GR-Lect.Notes.pdf

Comment: Right, it may be because I'm originally a mathematician, but to be fair this is the most weird formal manipulation I've seen in my life. I'll share what I understood, but bear in mind that all of these manipulations are *extremely* formal. View your equation as $$\dfrac{d|0\rangle_{\rm in}}{da^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)}=c(k) a^\dagger_{\rm out}(-k)|0\rangle_{\text in},$$ where $c(k)= -\frac{\beta^\ast(-k)}{\alpha(k)}$.  Now imagine somwhow you can manipulate this as $$\dfrac{d|0\rangle_{\rm in}}{|0\rangle_{\rm in}}=c(k) a^\dagger_{\rm out}(-k)da^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)|0\rangle_{\text in}.$$

Comment: Integrating, the LHS would be $\log |0\rangle_{\rm in}$. On the RHS observe that $a^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)$ and $a^\dagger_{\rm out}(-k)$ are "independent variables". As such your are really integrating a constant. This means you get on the RHS $$c(k)a^\dagger_{\rm out}(-k)a^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)|0\rangle_{\rm in}+\xi,$$ where this object $\xi$ is a constant with respect to the "variable" $a^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)$. As such it has to obey $\frac{d}{da^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)}\xi=0$. But he argued that this derivative is essentially $a_{\rm out}(k)$. As such this $\xi$ obeys $a_{\rm out}(k)\xi=0$.

Comment: This is the definition of the out vacuum. But then, $\log |0\rangle_{\rm out}$ also works, so you can choose this "constant" like this and send it to the LHS. In the end you get $$\log\frac{|0\rangle_{\rm in}}{|0\rangle_{\rm out}}=c(k)a^\dagger_{\rm out}(-k)a^\dagger_{\rm out}(k)|0\rangle_{\rm in}$$ Again, I find this the weirdest thing I've ever seem. I'll try to remember where there is a more rigorous derivation of the final result, which is his equation 8.35.